# Email Reminder doesnt triggered (to send) even Value Change from Formula in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VB in Excel.
I made an email reminder program in Excel with value changed from formula (calculation) in one of the cell. 
The problem is the email reminder did not pop up even though the conditions are met.
But when I put manually the number (to meet the condition), the email reminder did pop up. 
Please help to make the program run if the cell value from calculation met the condition of the program. Thanks! 
Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim completed As Boolean
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Objek As String
    Dim SatKer As String
    Dim Hari As String
    Dim AlamatEmail As String
    Dim xMailBody As String
    rowCount = 2
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    For i = 1 To 5
        rowCount = rowCount + 1
        Set xRg = Range("O" & CStr(rowCount))
        Objek = ActiveSheet.Range("F" & CStr(rowCount)).Value
        SatKer = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & CStr(rowCount)).Value
        Hari = ActiveSheet.Range("O" & CStr(rowCount)).Value
        AlamatEmail = ActiveSheet.Range("S" & CStr(rowCount)).Value
        If xRg = Target And Target.Value < 4 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook(Objek, SatKer, Hari, AlamatEmail)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook(Objek As String, SatKer As String, Hari As String, AlamatEmail As String)
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Yth. Bapak Widi " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "Laporan Penilaian " & Objek & " milik " & SatKer & " mendekati batas akhir pengumpulan." & vbNewLine & _
                "Laporan tersebut harus disubmit dalam " & Hari & " hari." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "Mohon cek status laporan penilaian untuk keterangan laporan lebih detail."
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = AlamatEmail
        .cc = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Laporan Penilaian " & Objek & " milik " & SatKer
        .HTMLBody = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. You need `Worksheet_Change` not `Worksheet_SelectionChange`. 2. Changes in a cell from a formula do not trigger a change event. You need static vars in a `Worksheet_Calculation`.

Comment: 3. Your If statement does not do what you think it does. Compare range addresses instead of ranges (xRg.Address = Target.Address)

Comment: @jeeped I tried with Worksheet_Change but it still did not pop up. what do you mean by static vars in worksheet_Calculation?

Comment: @Sam  I tried to change this:
        Set xRg.Address = Range("O" & CStr(rowCount))
        If xRg.Address = Target And Target.Address < 4 Then
But still doesnt work.

Comment: There at least a dozen examples of this method on this site. If your narrative was more precise I might have a try but I'm having a hard time determining your intent from the code.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks! I'll try to look for it. The intent of my code is to send an email to remind user if the due date of activities are coming (<4 means the remaining days are less than 4 days). I set the formula in the cell O, which calculate automatically in excel from the date of today to the due date. When the calculation result is <4 the email doesnt show up, but when I put number less than 4 manually, the email does pop up from outlook.

Comment: google **site:stackoverflow.com Worksheet_Calculate static**. There at least 3 examples on the first page of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do what you expect, the code will loop through column O and if the value calculated is less than 4 then it will .Display the email:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row
    'get the last row with data on Column O
    Dim completed As Boolean
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Objek As String
    Dim SatKer As String
    Dim Hari As String
    Dim AlamatEmail As String
    Dim xMailBody As String

    For i = 3 To LastRow 'loop from row 3 to last on Column O

        Set xRg = Range("O" & i)
        Objek = ws.Range("F" & i).Value
        SatKer = ws.Range("G" & i).Value
        Hari = ws.Range("O" & i).Value
        AlamatEmail = ws.Range("S" & i).Value

        If ws.Cells(i, "O").Value < 4 Then 'if value is less than 4 then send email
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook(Objek, SatKer, Hari, AlamatEmail)
        End If

    Next i
End Sub


Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook(Objek As String, SatKer As String, Hari As String, AlamatEmail As String)
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Yth. Bapak Widi " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "Laporan Penilaian " & Objek & " milik " & SatKer & " mendekati batas akhir pengumpulan." & vbNewLine & _
                "Laporan tersebut harus disubmit dalam " & Hari & " hari." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "Mohon cek status laporan penilaian untuk keterangan laporan lebih detail."
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = AlamatEmail
        .cc = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Laporan Penilaian " & Objek & " milik " & SatKer
        .HTMLBody = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```